# Unioned select statements cause an int overflow error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run this unioned select statement and I'm getting an int overflow error.
The first select has an ID which is an integer so I've cast it as a varchar(25).
This levels the playing field, or so I thought, because the ID values in the subsequent two selects with a maximum size of varchar(25).
This is the error.

> The conversion of the varchar value '24546133202216601' overflowed an int column

This might be a duplicate, but I couldn't find an identical question, so is there a way around this?

```
SELECT CAST(ID AS varchar(25)) AS thisID FROM tblA
UNION
SELECT ID AS thisID FROM tblB
UNION
SELECT ID AS thisID FROM tblC
```

Comment: Do you say both tblB and tblC have varchar(25) ID columns?

Comment: @jarlh yes - up to a max of 25 but never null

Comment: `int` has a (much) higher data type precedence than `varchar`, so your `varchar` will be implicitly converting to an `int`, and (unsurprisingly) that causes as error.

Comment: In some DBMS the first expression determines the type as you say. In others not. In SQL Server this is not the case. Here int has precedence over varchar as Larnu says. It looks like your first ID is a bigint, while the following ones are int. (Or it's int and smallint or tinyint, well a bigger int type in the first table than in one of the others.) You convert that big int to a string and the DBMS converts it to an int and the big int number doesn't fit in the int. The solution: Cast the other IDs to varchar(25), too.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner good thinking but i tried that and the result is the same

Comment: If you cast all IDs to varchar(25), then there is no int left in the query. It seems you cannot get the error then, unless there is a bug in that SQL Server version.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with some sample data which reproduces this issue - because as it stands, if as you say all ID columns are now `varchar(25)` - its not possible to get this error.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#arguments)

> The data types must be compatible.

> The definitions of the columns that are part of a UNION operation
> don't have to be the same, but they must be compatible through
> implicit conversion. When data types differ, the resulting data type
> is determined based on the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).